# favicon for href to javascript

Tags: javascript, href, favicon

I have a button on my website that you can drag into your bookmarks to present an iframe while being on another website. The button code looks like this:

```
<a href="javascript:(function(){...})" ...
```

Is it possible to give this a favicon that will be displayed in the bookmarks?

Comment: There are questions on stackoverflow with solutions, try them out. I am not going to close as a duplicate since no one selected answers on them. Do a search.

Comment: Can you tell me the term I should search for, when looking for information on this topic?

Comment: [favicon bookmarklet](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=favicon+bookmarklet)